# Back button closes TWO activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

**SOLVED!**

My Activity Stack looks like this, excuse the rough diagram!

```
A-->B-->C
    '-->D
```

If I press back button in activity `B` I go back to `A` as expected.
However, if I press back button in Activity `C` or `D` I go back to A instead of `B`.
In my mind this could be caused by two things 
1)Activity `B` quits when it opens the intents for `C` or `D`
2)the back button is somehow being called twice?

I have looked closely at the click listeners in activity `B` that start the intents expecting to find a `finish()` call in there but there isn't. 
I also check the `onBackPressed()` methods of activites `C` and `D` to see if I was manually opening activity A...but I wasn't.

here's the onResume method of activity `A`

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        screenOn(SCREEN_ON_DURATION);
        mWakeLock.acquire();

    }
```

here's the way I'm starting intents C and D

```
            Bundle info = new Bundle(); 
            info.putString("classId", ""+classId );


            Intent intent = new Intent(Notebook.this, StudentChooser.class);
            intent.putExtras(info); 

            Notebook.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Can anyone help?

Edit:  I discovered finish() in my onUserLeaveHint() that's what the problem was!

Comment: Can you replicate this problem inside the emulator? Make sure your device is OK. Are you overriding onBackPressed() or onResume() anywhere?

Comment: What's the intent parameter you brought up Activity B? maybe you removed it from stack?

Comment: One more point to check: B's onActivityResult. if you open D with `startActivityForResult()` and B's `onActivityResult()` calls `finish()`, B will be closed when D closed.

Comment: I thought @kingori might have had the answer but I don't have a `onActivityResult()` :-( Thanks to everyone else's suggestions, I've edited the question accordiongly. @ntkachov I can't check the app on the emulator as I'm using s database created on the phone and don't know how to move it

Comment: @xandy, I added my intent code to the question, I don't know how to mess with the activity stack so it's not something I'm doing intentionally anyway!

Comment: in the manifest file did you mention `no history` by any chance for activity B ?

Comment: Oh what an an idiot I am! I discovered `finish()` in my `onUserLeaveHint()`
Unfortunately I can't self-answer questions until my rep goes up, I'll edit it as solved
  
            
My sloppy copy-pasting!

Thanks to everyone for their help and for forcing me to look more carefully for `finish()`methods!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
The reason may be that you are using finish() in your previous activity,For example
A->B->C
            Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

finish() is destroying B activity hence the control is going on activity A on back button
```